# OWASP Zap Docker scan spidering out-of-scope items

Tags: owasp, zap

When starting a scan with `docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://10.1.2.3/zapwave` the spider will follow back to the root URL `https://10.1.2.3` and continue to scan out of scope items. eg `/ghost, /mono, /webgoat`

Is it possible to limit the scan scope to just the specified directory or below?  The web application in this example is OWASP DWVA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't passed it a context file from which it would constraint to scope.

The baseline scan documentation is here:
https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-Baseline-Scan

In particular you probably care about:
`-n context_file   context file which will be loaded prior to spidering the target`

You should probably also have a look at:
https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/01/25/setting-a-baseline-for-web-security-controls/

Also it's probably easiest to configure, test, and export the context from the GUI before trying to use it with automation.